# calling a service from an other file on the same machine

Tags: ros, callback, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I am a newbie to ROS, I am trying to make my ARDRONE more intelligent by using Brown's package for ARDRONE.T I
I need to call this service
:

```
bool toggleCamCallback(std_srvs::Empty::Request& request, std_srvs::Empty::Response& response)
{
  if (cam_state == 0) // toggle to 1, the vertical camera
    {
      cam_state = 1;
#ifdef _USING_SDK_1_7_
      ARDRONE_TOOL_CONFIGURATION_ADDEVENT (video_channel, &cam_state, NULL);
#else
      ardrone_at_set_toy_configuration("video:video_channel","1");
#endif
      fprintf(stderr, "\nToggling from frontal camera to vertical camera.\n");
    }
  else if (cam_state == 1) // toggle to the forward camera
    {
      cam_state = 0;
#ifdef _USING_SDK_1_7_
      ARDRONE_TOOL_CONFIGURATION_ADDEVENT (video_channel, &cam_state, NULL);
#elsebool toggleCamCallback(std_srvs::Empty::Request& request, std_srvs::Empty::Response& response)
{
  if (cam_state == 0) // toggle to 1, the vertical camera
    {
      cam_state = 1;
#ifdef _USING_SDK_1_7_
      ARDRONE_TOOL_CONFIGURATION_ADDEVENT (video_channel, &cam_state, NULL);
#else
      ardrone_at_set_toy_configuration("video:video_channel","1");
#endif
      fprintf(stderr, "\nToggling from frontal camera to vertical camera.\n");
    }
  else if (cam_state == 1) // toggle to the forward camera
    {
      cam_state = 0;
#ifdef _USING_SDK_1_7_
      ARDRONE_TOOL_CONFIGURATION_ADDEVENT (video_channel, &cam_state, NULL);
#else
      ardrone_at_set_toy_configuration("video:video_channel","0");
#endif
      fprintf(stderr, "\nToggling from vertical camera to frontal camera.\n");      
    }
  return true;
}
      ardrone_at_set_toy_configuration("video:video_channel","0");
#endif
      fprintf(stderr, "\nToggling from vertical camera to frontal camera.\n");      
    }
  return true;
}
```

I was able to invoke the service by entering the command: "rosservice call/ardrone/togglecam"*

But ,I am trying to find a way to call the service from other file(so that I can toggle between the cameras easily)
please help!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12465/calling-a-service-from-an-other-file-on-the-same-machine/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [service client tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node). This gives an example of making a simple service client in C++ and calling the service from that C++ code, as opposed to with rosservice on the command line.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2